# Правописание. Чтение

Tags: орфография, общие-вопросы

Читаю много, а пишу с ошибками. Что делать?

Comment: Неконкретный вопрос. Непонятно, что есть уже сейчас. Можете ли проанализировать ошибки по типам -- какие допускаете чаще и дописать в вопрос. Непонятно, что хотите получить на выходе. Может быть вам достаточно порекомендовать спеллчекерами пользоваться -- и бог с ними, с ошибками. Или личного секретаря нанять, чтобы он ваши тексты проверял.

Answer (score 3):

Значит, не вдумчиво читаете, бегло, следовательно, нужно не только читать, но и писать: переписывать тексты (только грамотных авторов, лучше классику). Выработается моторная память, рука запомнит, как пишутся слова. Но писать нужно много, как та студентка, что за год переписала "Войну и мир" и стала самой грамотной студенткой на курсе, хотя на экзамене получила "2".